# How do I run a scheduled AWS Lambda function, where scheduled time is a parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scheduled-tasks

I am wondering if it's possible to run a cron job using AWS Lambda with input parameters.

Example: 
I call my API endpoint: `api.example.com/LambdaFunction5?timestamp=1571299919&someOtherVariable=NetworkBytes`

As you can see, it's a get request to my API will which takes two parameters, an Epoch timestamp (1 day from now) and another parameter (can be anything). This API call will then make a con job that will be executed on the given timestamp using the other parameter as a variable in the lambda function.

How would I achieve this with AWS Lambda? I know that AWS allows me to schedule lambdas for specific times:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html

But the problem is that I don't want to create a new lambda function every time I want a cron job.

Is it a way to do this so when I call my API endpoint, it will create a cron job based on the time I give and run only once and "delete" itself after that job is run, so I don't end up with a million different functions or CloudWatch rules?

Comment: If I had to do this, I probably won't use AWSLambda since it seems clear there is no clean solution to achieve this.

That said, if you really want to do it, maybe that you can use the AWS SDK to change the schedule at 2 key moments :
- after your cron runs, by setting the next cron date to run (or a very far date to ensure it won't run before another schedule is added)
- on the POST call if : there is no schedule or the current schedule is later than the actual added schedule

You will have to store schedules somewhere to do so.

Answer (score 3):

you may define custom json attributes to be sent with the cloudwatch event:

- Go to Amazon EventBridge > Events > Rules
- clic on your rule
- click "Edit" button on the top right corner
- scroll down to "Select targets"
- clic on "Configure Inputs“
- select "Constant (JSON text)" radio button
- Add in the editable field the json data with your parameters.

You may encounter a bug in the console that forbids you to edit via the console. You may need to use the CLI (I don't have the syntax for that yet, sorry). Bug is here: https://github.com/concurrencylabs/aws-pricing-tools/issues/8

bug is closed but still present nonetheless.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I edited my post to add a full working solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can integrate Lambda with API Gateway proxy integration to achieve this. API Gateway will invoke your lambda on your behalf & pass URL parameter as part of event object during Lambda execution. Please refer to

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy

Detailed tutorial here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html

Comment: Yes, I already have an API running with AWS Lambda and API Gateway. My question is how I would be able to make Lambda create Cron Jobs on demand and scheduled for a specific date.

Comment: Attach a cloudwatch event in your Lambda Designer console, you can specify cron jobs up to minutes interval. I would suggest to split the Lambda func that run with API Gateway from the scheduled Lambda func.

Comment: @EthanNguyen Cron job is for repeating scheduled events. The OP is asking for passing a timestamp in the future to schedule a lambda function. Goal is to have a lambda function scheduled to run on hundreds of different one-time schedules, where the schedules are timestamps given in POST parameter of request to API gateway. How do you do this? I've done it by making a webhook scheduler project that uses setIntervals to trigger webhooks but this is not a clean solution